# Is it possible to place a sub or function on one line in vba?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to place a sub on one line in Access VBA. 
Is there a setting or special syntax that can be used to accomplish this?

```
    private sub cmd_print() docmd.printout end sub 'creates an error
```

vs

```
    private sub cmd_print() 
    docmd.printout 
    end sub
```

Comment: You do have a one line `IF` statement. `IIF(expr,x,y)`

Comment: @ja72 It [works differently](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13050787/11683) though.

Comment: @ja72 The inline `If` statement syntax is totally legal: `If expr Then DoSomething Else DoSomethingElse`, `IIf` is a *function*, not a statement.

Comment: @Mat'sMug good point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Technically*, yes, using the *instructions separator* - the colon `:` token:

```
Private Sub PrintCommand() : DoCmd.PrintOut : End Sub
```

I would **strongly** advise against it though, for obvious maintainability and readability reasons.

This particular layout is used by some add-ins such as vbWatchDog, for some generated code. <s>Because of how it challenges the expected structure of a module, it is [known to cause problems with add-ins that process the code, such as Rubberduck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/2665) (which I'm heavily involved with)</s> (parser has been updated since then; this is no longer an issue) - that's because the *member attributes* will be stored (you need to export the module to see them, the VBE doesn't display module and member attributes), rather counter-intuitively, *outside* the procedure scope:

```
Private Sub PrintCommand() : DoCmd.PrintOut : End Sub
Attribute PrintCommand.VB_Description = "This procedure does XYZ"
```

The "normal" layout looks like this, and doesn't cause issues:

```
Private Sub PrintCommand()
Attribute PrintCommand.VB_Description = "This procedure does XYZ"
    DoCmd.PrintOut
End Sub
```

It's easier to read, too.

Comment: Hey thanks, My own readability of my code is what drove this question. I find it more readable because it allows for more screen real estate along the y axis of my monitor.

Comment: Cramming code in as little vertical space as possible rarely *improves* readability, **especially** when scopes are involved. YMMV.