# IIf vs if-else in VBA

Tags: vba, if-statement, iif-function

I couldn't find anything specific for VBA but as far as I checked the answers (for other languages) in VBA this code

```
If A then B else C
```

is essentially the same as

```
IIf(A,B,C)
```

The only difference is that the IIF-function is a little more compact. I tested the performance, there is no significant change there either. Did I miss anything?

Edit: thanks to whoever posted the link to the [VB6 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050731/vb6-iif-advantage) in the comments. Although VB6 and VBA are very similar they are still two separate implementations and they do not work "exactly" in the same way. In my opinion, this question should be left open since it specifically applies to VBA and not VB6 (but so far I didn't find any differences for the IIF implementation).

Comment: If anything, IIf will be slower because it evaluates both B and C whereas an If will only evaluate B or C.

Comment: `IIf` works exactly in the same way in [VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iif-function) and [VB6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa445024(v=vs.60)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), and even in VB.NET. There is similarly looking [`If` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/if-operator) in VB.NET that is something different, but it's only in VB.NET.