# Calling Windows API function with an argument using CStr(IIF(....)) doesn't work. Why?

Tags: vba

Can you explain why the last line is not the same as the previous two lines and doesn't work?  (it doesn't find any window)

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As LongPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As LongPtr, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As LongPtr

Working =    FindWindowEx(hWnd2, 0&, "EXCEL7", vbNullString)
Working =    FindWindowEx(hWnd2, 0&, "EXCEL7", CStr(vbNullString))
NotWorking = FindWindowEx(hWnd2, 0&, "EXCEL7", CStr(IIf(1 = 1, vbNullString, vbNullString)))
```

Comment: `IIf` is a [mere function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13050787/11683), and it returns a `Variant`. It so happens that, when packing the result into the `Variant` it returns, it provides a copy and not the original value, which happens for non-vbnullstrings too. A copy of `vbNullString` is a zero-length string at a non-null address, which is [not equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20909528/11683) to `vbNullString` as you have found out. It is equivalent only as far as the VB's `=` comparison goes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I experimented a bit. First: I can confirm the behavior.

Then I had a closer look to the difference. I used an intermediate variable to store the 4th parameter and dumped some information. My conclusion: `vbNullString` returns a null pointer (and `CStr(vbNullString)`).

However, the IIF-function will not return a null pointer: It needs to copy the content of either the if or the else branch to a new location (a new memory address). The content at this location is again an empty string, but it seems that `FindWindowEx` does something with it (I am not really familiar with that function).

```
Const Windowname = "IrfanView"  ' Had to change that
Dim res
Dim hWnd2 As LongPtr
Dim nullStr As String

nullStr = vbNullString
res = FindWindowEx(hWnd2, 0&, Windowname, nullStr)
Debug.Print VarType(res), res, VarType(nullStr), StrPtr(nullStr)

nullStr = CStr(vbNullString)
res = FindWindowEx(hWnd2, 0&, Windowname, nullStr)
Debug.Print VarType(res), res, VarType(nullStr), StrPtr(nullStr) 

nullStr = IIf(1 = 1, vbNullString, vbNullString)
res = FindWindowEx(hWnd2, 0&, Windowname, nullStr)
Debug.Print VarType(res), res, VarType(nullStr), StrPtr(nullStr)
```

Output:

```
 20            4134988       8             0 
 20            4134988       8             0 
 20            0             8             2346722344360
```

Comment: `seems that FindWindowEx does something with it` - yes, it [compares it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowexa#parameters) to the window captions, thus looking for a window with an empty caption, which is different from looking for a window with any caption.

Comment: You miss the "CStr(IIf..." test, that is what I'm surprised to see that doesn't work

Comment: @6diegodiego9 The `CStr` does not change the outcome of the `IIf`.

Comment: Ok I completely understood the dynamics now, thanks @Greg and @FunThomas!